# How to pass var as another method`s parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing, var

I am making a windows application.

At first I declared var and it contains another class method.

`var ExtList = ExtTarget.GetExtTargets();`

And GetExtTargets() is like this

```
public static List<ExtTarget> GetExtTargets()
{
    var dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(QueryHelper.ConnectionString,
        @"
        SELECT [seq],[SourceKind],[ExtKind],[DBKind],[ConnectionString]
              ,[FilePath],[TableName],[FileKind],[RowSplitter],[ColumnSplitter]
              ,[Title],[GroupName],[SyncOrder],[RepeatKind],[RepeatMonth]
              ,[RepeatDay],[RepeatHour],[RepeatMin],[RepeatWeek],[RepeatWeekNum]
              ,[LastSyncExecDate]
        FROM [ExtTarget]
        order by GroupName,SyncOrder");
   return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select<DataRow, ExtTarget>(a => ExtTarget.RowToModel(a)).ToList();
}
```

Then, I used it to foreach and then I want to pass Ext to another method's parameter.

Code is like this.

```
public void ProcessExtSync(object obj)
{
    while (IsProcessGoing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(ThreadDelay);
        if (!IsProcessGoing) return;

        var ExtList = ExtTarget.GetExtTargets();
        foreach (var Ext in ExtList) // I want to use this Ext as parameter
        {
            while (IsSourceSyncGoing)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(ThreadDelay);
            }
            IsExtSyncGoing = true;
            bool ExtSyncForceToRun = ConfigSettingHelper.Instance.IsServiceConfig(Words.ExtSyncForceToRun);
            bool ExtSyncForceToRunOnlyError = ConfigSettingHelper.Instance.IsServiceConfig(Words.ExtSyncForceToRunOnlyError);
            bool ExtSyncNeedToRun = ConfigSettingHelper.Instance.GetNextExecutingTime(Ext) < DateTime.Now;
            if (ExtSyncForceToRun || ExtSyncNeedToRun)
            {

                //I want to pass Ext as parameter to this method
                ServiceProcess.Instance.SyncExt();

                if (ExtSyncForceToRun)
                {
                    ConfigSettingHelper.Instance.SetServiceConfig(Words.ExtSyncForceToRun, false);
                }
                if (ExtSyncForceToRunOnlyError)
                {
                   ConfigSettingHelper.Instance.SetServiceConfig(Words.ExtSyncForceToRunOnlyError, false);
                }
            }
            if (!IsProcessGoing) return;
        }

        IsExtSyncGoing = false;
    }
}
```

How can I modify that code? Please help me.

Comment: Just pass it. It's a variable like any other. I don't understand what the problem is. Are you getting an error?

Comment: The same was as you've defined an argument for `ProcessExtSync`. If you don't know how to pass arguments to a method, you should probably run through a tutorial or pick up a C# book first.

Comment: In addition to @Rufus's answer, I would say do not use `var` in your case because that simply doesn't tell the reader what type `GetExtTargets()` is returning. When obvious, you can use `var`, e.g. `var op = "ryden"`.

Comment: Thank you for replied this post.  I modified my code based on all these advices and now, it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is just a shortcut way of implicitly typing a variable. It saves some typing, but sometimes makes code harder to read when the reader can't determine the type. The compiler can figure out the strong type, though (or you'll get a compiler error), and if you hover over it in Visual Studio, the compiler will tell you the actual type.

With that out of the way, all you need to do is make sure that the method you want to pass your variable to takes in the type that you want to pass it (remember the type is not `var`, but in your case it is an `ExtTarget`).

The method you're calling should have a signature similar to this (although it may return any type):

```
public void SyncExt(ExtTarget extTarget)
{ 
    // Implementation code here
}
```

Then in your code above you can call:

```
ServiceProcess.Instance.SyncExt(Ext);
```

Comment: Yeah, you`re correct. And I realized I need more study. Thank you Rufus L for your explanation and example source!